# Trying to build a stack with pointers and malloc. Unexpected output C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

so I'm trying to build a stack in C, using pointers and malloc.

My stack.h has a struct

```
typedef struct
{

int *top;
int *prev;

} intstack_t;
```

I'm initialising the stack like this:

```
int stackInit(intstack_t* self) {

    if(malloc(sizeof(self != NULL))) {
        self->top = malloc(sizeof(self->top));
        self->prev = malloc(sizeof(self->prev));
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
   }
}

void stackPush(intstack_t* self, int i) {

    self->prev = self->top;
    self->top = newElement(i);

}

int stackPop(intstack_t* self) {

    int tmp = *self->top;
    free(self->top);
    self->top = self->prev;
    return tmp;
}

int *newElement(int i) {
    int *new = malloc(sizeof(i));
    *new = i;
    return new;
}
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    intstack_t stack;
    stackInit(&stack);
    stackPush(&stack, 1);
    stackPush(&stack, 2);
    stackPush(&stack, 3);
    stackPop(&stack);
    printf("stackTop: %i \n", stackTop(&stack));
    stackPop(&stack);
    printf("stackTop: %i \n, stackTop(&stack));

    }
```

While I can push onto the stack, only the first pop yields the desired output. When I pop again the result is something completely different.

```
stackTop: 0 
stackTop: 1 
stackTop: 2 
stackTop: 3 
stackTop: 2 
stackTop: 34792624
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction, as I dont see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In `if(malloc(sizeof(self != NULL)))` why are you not saving the return value of `malloc()` somewhere? At minimum you'd need to `free()` that later.

Comment: haven't thought of that yet. Obviously you are right, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why are your elements just integers? How do you want to implement your stack? As a dynamic array or as linked list of nodes? (Given the many `malloc`s that your code has, I'm guessing the latter.)

Comment: The idea was to use a linked list of nodes.

Comment: Draw your data structure on paper and you'll find out by yourself what's wrong with your implementation.

Comment: This statement: `malloc(sizeof(self != NULL)))` is nonsense.  It is getting the size of a true/false condition.  if re arranged like: `malloc(sizeof(self)) != NULL` is still will not work as 'self' is a pointer so only gets enough room for a pointer.  if re-arranged like: `malloc(sizeof(*self ) ) != NULL` then it can get a pointer to an area that is large enough to hold one instance of a `intstack_t` struct..  However,  after generating that struct, how is the code expected to link all the data together?  Suggest searching stackoverflow.com for linked list implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One essential problem is that `struct intstack_t` does not contain any pointer to `intstack_t` - the previous element in the stack. It only contains pointers to two `int`s. That is, your implementation of stack cannot store more than two `int`s at all.

Answer (score 3):

- `if(malloc(sizeof(self != NULL)))` is nonsense code. I can't even make out any sense of your intention here. You need to store the allocated data somewhere and `sizeof(self != NULL)` is the size of a boolean expresion...
- Inside `int stackInit(intstack_t* self)` you don't return the allocated pointer to the caller, so no matter what you do inside that function it won't get returned to the caller.
- It is not clear why you must dynamically allocate the stack itself in the first place. `intstack_t stack;` already allocates this variable on the stack (the program's stack) before you call `stackInit(&stack);`.
- You must free() memory that you allocate.

And so on. Overall, the code makes no sense at all. It would seem that you are trying to write this program through trial & error programming, which will never work.